# Exhaust white smoke heavy now won't start 2001 325i BMW

Tags: bmw

[image]

smoke think from exhaust now won't start BMW 325 I  2001 brought recently from private owner

Comment: Is white or is it a little blueish? pull the dipstick/check under the oil fill cap. Does it look like a milkshake or is it black?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not getting what the image has to do with anything?